# Filter a collection in a PagedCollectionView

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a scenario wherein I have to filter a collection in a `PagedCollectionView`. 
The filter criteria are `Name` and status which are checkboxes with Enabled and Disabled labels. If `Enabled` is checked it should filter out the list with all enabled rules and vice-versa. I have given it a try, but I believe this isn't the best way of doing it.

```
     private PagedCollectionView _autoDepRuleList;
    public PagedCollectionView AutoDepRuleList
    {
        get
        {
            return this._autoDepRuleList;
        }
        set
        {
            this._autoDepRuleList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("AutoDepRuleList");
        }
    }        

    private bool _isEnabled;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return this._isEnabled;
        }
        set
        {
            this._isEnabled = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
        }
    }

    private bool _isDisabled;
    public bool IsDisabled
    {
        get
        {
            return this._isDisabled;
        }
        set
        {
            this._isDisabled = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsDisabled");
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._name;
        }
        set
        {
            this._name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

     public void Search()
    {
        var tempList = new AutoDeploymentRuleList();
        var filterList = new AutoDeploymentRuleList();

        foreach (AutoDeploymentRule item in this.AutoDepRuleList)
        {
            tempList.Add(item);
        }
        if (IsEnabled && IsDisabled)
        {
            foreach (var item in tempList)
            {
                filterList.Add(item);
            } 
        }
        else if (IsEnabled)
        {
            foreach (var item in tempList.Where(r => r.Status.Equals("Enabled")))
            {
                filterList.Add(item);
            } 
        }
        else if (IsDisabled)
        {
            foreach (var item in  tempList.Where(r => r.Status.Equals("Disabled")))
            {
                filterList.Add(item);
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in tempList)
            {
                filterList.Add(item);
            } 
        }
    this.AutoDepRuleList = new PagedCollectionView(filterList.Where(r => r.Name.ToLower().Contains(this.Name.ToLower())));
```

Now the idea is to do away with the above block and go for the below logic. I did it for the `Name` property, but I'm not sure how I can do it for the `Status` property which can be anything either `Enabled` or `Disabled`.

```
    this.AutoDepRuleList.Filter = new System.Predicate<object>(o =>
    {
        AutoDeploymentRule rule = (AutoDeploymentRule)o;

        if (rule.Name.ToLower().IndexOf(this.Name.Trim().ToLower()) >= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });          
}
```

How can I optimize it by removing those redundant where clauses and putting the entire thing under `Predicate<object>`?

Answer (score 3):

If performance is your concern, won't boxing and unboxing the variable unnecessarily add an overhead? Why would you want to do that?

Wouldn't this be much easier?

```
this.AutoDepRuleList //if this is queryable/enumerable, or convert first
.Where(r => (isDisabled && r.Status.Equals("Disabled")) || 
             (isEnabled && r.Status.Equals("Enabled")) ||
              (!isDisabled && !isEnabled))
//either ToList() if you just need to assign to another list, or ForEach if you want
//to iterate over list and do something
    .ForEach(filterList.Add);
```

Update: had forgotten the condition where both isDisabled and isEnabled were false.

Comment: you could also go var filterList = [Roopesh's linq].ToList()

Comment: yup.. any idea which is more efficient? Anyways I put a foreach there so it'll work if the method has some additional logic as well instead of just .Add().

Comment: hi @RoopeshShenoy, thanks for the post; as AutoDepRuleList is of type PagedCollectionView we can't apply linq methods to it directly,

           this.AutoDepRuleList.SourceCollection.OfType<AutoDeploymentRule>().Where(r => (IsDisabled && r.Status.Equals("Disabled")) ||
                 (IsEnabled && r.Status.Equals("Enabled")) ||
                  (!IsDisabled && !IsEnabled));

Comment: Great if it works for you!